# jQuery trigger event if anything has a class

Tags: jquery, class

Using jQuery, How would I trigger an event if ANYTHING on the page has a class of 'error'.
I tired using jQuery("*"), but how would i integrate that into an IF statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function(){
  if($('.error').length) {
  doSomething()
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this test :

```
if ($('.error').length) {
```

This will check if anything on the page has the class `error`.